# Literal suffix for byte in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, value-type

I am wondering if there is any way to declare a byte variable in a short way like floats or doubles? I mean like `5f` and `5d`. Sure I could write `byte x = 5`, but that's a bit inconsistent if you use `var` for local variables.

Comment: Most people here seem to assume `var` is the only use case. There are other valid use cases. For example, `byte value = condition ? (byte)5 : (byte)6`.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

There is no mention of a literal suffix on the [MSDN reference for Byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) as well as in the [C# 4.0 Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx). The only literal suffixes in C# are for integer and real numbers as follows:

```
u = uint
l = long
ul = ulong
f = float
m = decimal
d = double
```

If you want to use `var`, you can always cast the byte as in `var y = (byte) 5`

Although not really related, in C#7, a new binary prefix was introduced `0b`, which states the number is in binary format. Still there is no suffix to make it a byte though, example:

```
var b = 0b1010_1011_1100_1101_1110_1111; //int
```

Comment: `0b1010_1011_1100_1101_1110_1111` is still an `Int32` though.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the C# 7 document where `0b` is covered.

Comment: Another use case would be data-driven testing and the `DataRowAttribute`,which requires casting to byte to avoid the following if the test fails: ."Cannot widen from source type to target type either because the source type is a not a primitive type or the conversion cannot be accomplished."

Comment: This works: `[DataRow((byte)207, (byte)2)]`

Comment: This doesn't work as well: `[DataRow(207, 2)]`

Answer (score 31):

> So, we added binary literals in VB last fall and got similar feedback
>   from early testers. We did decide to add a suffix for byte for VB. We
>   settled on SB (for signed byte) and UB (for unsigned byte). The reason
>   it's not just B and SB is two-fold.
>
> One, the B suffix is ambiguous if you're writing in hexadecimal (what
>   does 0xFFB mean?) and even if we had a solution for that, or another
>   character than 'B' ('Y' was considered, F# uses this) no one could
>   remember whether the default was signed or unsigned - .NET bytes are
>   unsigned by default so it would make sense to pick B and SB but all
>   the other suffixes are signed by default so it would be consistent
>   with other type suffixes to pick B and UB. In the end we went for
>   unambiguous SB and UB.
>   -- Anthony D. Green,

https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/542111

Apparently, it seems that they've done this move in VB.NET (might not be released right now), and they might implement it in roslyn for C# - go give your vote, if you think that's something you'd like. You'd also have a chance to propose a possible syntax.

Comment: The suffix is still not listed on the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx) (updated July 20, 2015).

Comment: And still does not seem to be implemented in VS 2017.

Comment: Nor in VS 2019. As per the MSDN page cited above (updated 01/30/2018): _No identifier type characters exist for the Boolean, Byte, Char, Date, Object, SByte, Short, UInteger, ULong, or UShort data types, or for any composite data types such as arrays or structures._

Comment: @Pona The `UL` suffix works for `ulong` (`UInt64`) though.

Comment: Are you seriously claiming that there's a real feature (one that actually is wanted) implemented in VB but not in C#?! I'm terminating this reality...    :D

Answer (score 12):

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(v=VS.100).aspx) MSDN page, it would seem that your only options are to cast explicitly (`var x = (byte)5`), or stop using `var`...

Comment: It's not just about `var`.  For example, `this.pixels[x, y] = condition ? (byte)0 : (byte)1;`

Comment: @JohnGietzen, exactly! In my case it's `Math.Max(myByte, (byte)1)`.
And BTW, you can replace your example to: `this.pixels[x, y] = (byte)(condition ? 0 : 1);`, which to me looks a bit nicer, or `this.pixels[x, y] = Convert.ToByte(!condition);`

Comment: How about using in attributes? e.g. xunit: `[InlineData(1)]` - `[InlineData(1b)]` would look way better than `[InlineData((byte)1)]` (using only `1` could throw an exception if the parameter is nullable byte and you give it an int)

Comment: another example - dependency property in wpf of type byte. if you write 0xff as default value you get exception in runtime