# Bad default value exception when parsing options with CommandLine lib

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I have used CommandLine library for parsing it pass for string type, int type, bool type but it not pass for byte type, I have got an exception `"Bad default value."`

```
    [Option("m", null, DefaultValue = 0, HelpText = "help")]
    public byte mm { get; set; }
```

Why I get this exception and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal `0` is an `Int32` per compiler default. You need to specify a `byte` to match the type of the property.

Unfortunatly [there is no `byte` literal symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5378070/5528593) in c#, so you'll need to cast it explicitly:

```
[Option("m", null, DefaultValue = (byte)0, HelpText = "help")]
public byte mm { get; set; }
```

Comment: it works now, I don't know this information before because I'm newer C# developer