# How to set the high-nibble of a Byte?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Given a `Byte` (e.g. 0x49), i want to change the high-nibble from `4` to `7`.

That is:

> `0x49` → `0x79`

I've tried the following:

```
Byte b = 0x49;
b = 0x70 | (b & 0x0f);
```

But it fails to compile:

> Compilation error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What am i doing wrong?

### CMRE

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //The goal is to change the high nibble of 0x49 from 4 to 7.  That is 0x49 ==> 0x79
        Byte b = 0x49;
        b = b & 0x0f;
        b = 0x70 | b;
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/V3bplL

I've tried casting every piece i can find as `(Byte)`, but it still complains. And rather than firing a hard-cast cannon at the code, and hoping something sticks, i figured i would get the **correct** answer.

That's why the example code contains no `(Byte)` casts:

- it shouldn't be needed
- i want someone else to explain to me exactly where, and exactly *why*, it or they **is** or **are** needed

Hence the easy to click `dotnetfiddle` link. People can try it for themselves, add a `(Byte)` cast, see it fails to compile, go *"Huh"*, and try adding more casts randomly.

### For those who didn't read

For the pedants who didn't bother to try it:

```
Byte b = (Byte)0x49;
b = ((Byte)0x70) | ((Byte)(((Byte)b) & ((Byte)((Byte)0x0f))));
```

also fails.

Comment: What about adding a cast?

Comment: @Progman Do you think adding a cast will help? What about six?

Comment: There's no byte literal suffix, hence why it's interpreted as int.  You need the cast.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378036/literal-suffix-for-byte-in-net

Comment: See [OR-ing bytes in C# gives int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214629/or-ing-bytes-in-c-sharp-gives-int) and [Why do C#'s binary operators always return int regardless of the format of their inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079986/why-do-cs-binary-operators-always-return-int-regardless-of-the-format-of-their)

Comment: @DeanGoodman That's correct but it's not the whole story. Just `b = b & b;` would trigger the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit manipulating a `Byte` *returns* an `Int32`:

- `Byte` & `Byte` → `Int32`
- `Byte` | `Byte` → `Int32`

So you need to cast in order to not have your intermediate expressions be interpreted as an `int`:

```
Byte b = 0x49;
b = (Byte)(b & 0x0f);
b = (Byte)(0x70 | b);
```

Or simply:

```
Byte b = 0x49;
b = (Byte)(0x70 | (b & 0x0f));
```

Comment: That's very odd. Why is it that adding casts does not work here? `b = ((Byte)0x70) | ((Byte)(((Byte)b) & ((Byte)((Byte)0x0f))));`

Comment: In that case you aren't casting the overall expression: `b = (byte) (0x70 | (byte)(b & 0x0f))`.

Comment: @gbishop3 Ahhh! The lack of a literal `Byte` suffix is a red-herring. The real issue is that `byte | byte` results in an `int`! That makes perfect sense in C#.

Comment: Maybe not quite a red-herring - I'd expect if there *was* such a suffix that `0x70x | b` (where x is our fictional suffix) *would* in fact evaluate to a `Byte`.  That's my expectation of a language feature that doesn't exist, so your point about `byte | byte` resulting in `int` is taken as it's the reality of the language today.

Comment: Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3079999/12597) they talk about how it's because `Byte` has no `&` operator defined; so the values have to be promoted to `int`. And then you need to manually throw away the upper 16-bits. Tedious; very tedious.